# Add attributes to the nested field

Tags: php, symfony

How can I add attributes to a nested field `PasswordType` (attribute `always_empty`)? This code doesn't work:

```
   $builder
        ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
            'type' => PasswordType::class, [
                'always_empty' => false
            ],
            'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
            'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
        ])
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It belongs in the 'options' array.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#options

```
$builder
    ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
        'type' => PasswordType::class,
        'options' => ['always_empty' => false],
        'first_options'  => ['label' => 'Password'],
        'second_options' => ['label' => 'Repeat Password'],
    ])
;
```